# Arrays Of Image Data are Different Lengths? Python PIL

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I have a program to break an image down into 1s and 0s (shown below). My problem is that the arrays are different lengths for different images (taken with the same webcam and no compression).

Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
def read(filename):
    image = Image.open(filename, 'r')

    basewidth = 300
    wpercent = (basewidth/float(image.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(image.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
    image = image.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    width, height = image.size
    print(width)
    print(height)
    data = list(image.getdata())

    binData = []

    for i in data:
        for j in i:
            tempBin = str(bin(j))
            for k in tempBin:
                if k != "b":
                    binData.append(int(k))
    print(len(binData))
    return binData
```

I am confused because I took the pictures at the same time with the same webcam, same resolution. They are different file sizes, but I don't know why.

Thanks for any solutions you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIL can convert JPEG to BMP. JPEG is compressed (frequency domain and quantised, so even if it’s lossless, two images can be different sizes just because of their content). BMP is just RGB (red, green, blue) values for each pixel plus a header. For images with the same height and width, the .bmp file will be the same size (headers plus height x width x 3 channels). The jpeg files will be smaller, though.

Of course, getdata() will return pixel values regardless.

If you convert bytes to binary to strings, then you need to have all the binary strings the same length, and you may need to manually add preceding 0s to some binary strings.

Comment: I converted the images to bmps, and they are still slightly off.

Comment: Same height and width? What are the file sizes (in bytes or bits)?

Comment: Yes, same height and width. File size from my program are 1,284,116 and 1,267,967.

Comment: Wait, your code looks like it converts pixels to strings? And then appends each character in the string to a list? The strings wouldn’t be the same size for the same reason that although 1 and 10 are both integers, there is only one character in 1 and two characters in 10.

Comment: Ah, does bin() pre-pend zeros? That is, does it return '00000001' for the decimal value 1? Or does it just return '1'?

Comment: That was my issue. I fixed it with a while loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't show us the images, but could it be because of compression? JPG files are compressed, and many other file formats are.

Even two pictures taken a short while from eachother are a bit different and compress differently, hence the 'same resolution, different files sizes'.

Comment: That makes sense; is there a solution you can propose?

Comment: Would taking a picture in raw help?

Comment: Depends if "raw" means lossless JPEG or RGB values without headers. Check the size of the array produced. If it’s (heigh * width * 3) then the data is likely RGB data.